# Encapsulating the Order of a Collection in OOP

Tags: oop

Let's say you have a collection of objects that are part of a class:

[A, B, C, D]

But the order they are in means something. There are a finite number of orderings that you want to be able to delegate at runtime. For example [C, A, B, D], [B, D, A, C], etc. How would you go about encapsulating the notion of order in such a way that allows you to change the ordering at runtime, and add new orderings later on without changing existing code?

The language doesn't matter, but an explanation in Java or C++ is preferred.

Comment: Is the object collection set fixed? If it is, every possible order can be enumerated, and you can represent it, say with a single `int`. Then you change the `int` or add more `int`s for more collections in different order.